# Moving coordinates away from central point

Tags: math, geometry, coordinates

What I am currently trying to do is expand a group of dots on my screen away from a central point. I am currently using this code (Note I have modified this code to be easier to understand):

```
    #d_x - the x coordinate of the dot at its default position 
    #d_y - the y coordinate of the dot at its default position 
    #dis_x - the distance along the x grid the point is away from the centre point 
    #dis_y - the distance along the y grid the point is away from the centre point
    #zoom_level - the zoom level increased or decreased depending on the mouse wheel
z_x = (d_x + (dis_x * (1 + (zoom_level * 0.01))))
    z_y = (d_y + (dis_y * (1 + (zoom_level * 0.01))))
drawText("*",z_x,z_y,)
```

This code is almost working the only problem is that when zoom_level is 0 the dots are in the correct position but when I increase the zoom level the dots expand in the wrong direction instead of expanding outwards away from the central point the travel the opposite way, travelling towards the centre point.

Any advice on how to fix this problem will be much appreciated.

[EDIT] - I have not said this but each point is spread out at random points around the central point.

Comment: Works on my machine. See [here](http://pastebin.com/YvZV6Cxw). Performing 100,000 trials, the dot always traveled farther away from the central point when increasing the zoom level.

Comment: How are you calculating `dis_x` and `dis_y`?

Comment: Magic 8 Ball: Your `zoom level ` has the wrong +/- sign when the dots are moving in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1):

Let's central point has coordinates (c_x, c_y). Then (with default Zoom = 1)

```
z_x = c_x + (d_x - c_x) * Zoom
z_y = c_y + (d_y - c_y) * Zoom
```

Example: central point (black) (2,2), points (blue) (3,3) and (0,1)
zoom = 2: new points (red) (4,4) and (-2, 0)
[image]

Comment: Not quite sorry, They all bunch up and then as the zoom level increases they move towards the top left of the screen.

Comment: I may not have explained clearly but each dot is spread out around the central point at random positions